# Utilização de imagens em formato bitmap numa aplicação

Tags: java, android, xml

À título de experimentação para o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação mais avançada, estava a tentar fazer uma aplicação que consistia num botão e num componente `imageView`, de maneira a que quando premisse o botão fosse apresentada na `imageView` uma imagem tipo *bitmap* que tenho armazenada no telemóvel.

Contudo após executar a minha aplicação, o que acontece é que quando primo o botão não aparece nada, ou melhor, no `imageView` aparece uma imagem toda em branco. Penso que isto possa estar relacionado com o método `setImageBitmap()` ou até mesmo com a estrutura do código para a definição da diretoria dessa imagem.

Consigo fazer isso para o caso em que utilizo uma imagem JPEG por exemplo, e esta imagem está armazenada na pasta `drawable-mdpi` do pacote da minha aplicação. Neste caso utilizo o `setImageResource()` para fazer o display da imagem. Contudo o que pretendia mesmo era apresentar uma imagem que estivesse armazenada algures no meu telemóvel.

Ficheiro MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.showimages;

import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*; 
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    File imgFile;
    ImageView myImage;
    Bitmap myBitmap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        String sd_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        imgFile = new File(sd_path, "foto1.jpg");
        myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
        myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) { 
                myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                } 
            }); 
        }
}
```

Ficheiro activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.showimages.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="188dp"
        android:contentDescription="@android:string/VideoView_error_button"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Push" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Já consegui resolver! O problema estava relacionado com as permissões, pois eu não tinha colocado nenhuma...enfim...

Adicionei esta permissão e já funcionou corretamente!

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionar a seguinte permissão no manifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```